# SQL Server 2016 Temporal Tables are Blank

Tags: sql-server-2016, period, temporal-tables

I am trying to create a Temporal Table in SQL Server 2016. The Database is linked to an Azure Data factory which is updated regularly.

I am able to successfully 'create' the Temporal Table, but whenever I try to Select Rows from the table they are blank.

Code for Temporal Table Below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RecoTemp_Test2]   
   (
   [ObservationID] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [ObservationTitle] [text] NULL,
   [RecoReleaseDate] [date] NULL,
   [RecoIsReleased] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [ObservationRootCause] [text] NULL,
   [EntityID] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [AuditID] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoID] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
   [ObservationDescription] [text] NULL,
   [ObservationBusinessImpactRisk] [text] NULL,
   [RecoCode] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoTMState] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoTMSubState] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoPriority] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoEffortToComplete] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoProgressRate] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoLastFollowUpComments] [text] NULL,
   [RecoLastFollowUpUserID] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoLastFollowUpUserName] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoLastFollowUpDate] [date] NULL,
   [Reco3Pillars] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoTargetDate] [date] NULL,
   [RecoTargetDateRevised] [date] NULL,
   [RecoLastImplementedDate] [date] NULL,
   [RecoLastClosedDate] [date] NULL,
   [RecoDescription] [text] NULL,
   [RecoManagementActionPlan] [text] NULL,
   [RecoExpectedDeliverables] [text] NULL,
   [RecoIsPastDue] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoIsPastDueEoY] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoStatus] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoStatusLvl1] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoProgressRateLabel] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoClosingDeadline] [date] NULL,
   [RecoOrigin] [varchar](100) NULL,
   [RecoIssuedDate] [date] NULL,
   SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime),
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RecoID] ASC) 
   ) 
   WITH 
   ( 
   SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[RecoTemp_Test2_Hist])
   )
```

Comment: Which table is empty, the main table or the history? Have you actually inserted or updated any rows?

Comment: Please include a repro that causes the problem. The create table ddl creates an empty table. Selecting from it will not return rows